# get a return value from setInterval function

Tags: javascript

i have an ajax function which gets called and returns json data. this function is called via a setInterval loop:

```
    function SetMaxBidReload() {
        var reloadInt = 6000;
        var doReload = true;

        //set some logic here

        if (doReload) {
            setInterval(function () { ReloadMaxBid(); }, reloadInt);
        }
    }

    function ReloadMaxBid() {
        var nextReload;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxcall.aspx',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //change to dom elemants here based on return data
                nextReload = data[0].NextReload;
            }
        });
        return nextReload;

    }
```

what im trying to do is change the reloadInt of setInterval based on what comes back from the ajax call.

a: is that possible and b: how do i do it?

im open to suggestions on how to accomplish this by coding it differently

Comment: It's very likely that `ReloadMaxBid` always returns `undefined`, as the `success` handler probably won't be called before `ReloadMaxBid` returns.

Comment: indeed... i didnt even think of that. what is your suggestion to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` takes the timeout param once and then executes the function based on that interval, changing the `reloadInt` wouldn't have any effect whatsoever.

You need to use `setTimeout` in the success callback:

```
function ReloadMaxBid() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxcall.aspx',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //change to dom elemants here based on return data

            var next = data[0].NextReload;
            if (next !== -1) {
                setTimeout(function(){ReloadMaxBid();}, next);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You'd also need to use `setTimeout` with the value of `6000` somewhere to get things started.

Comment: As I've said in my (wrong) answer below, you can just pass the `ReloadMaxBid` function directly to `setTimeout`, without surrounding it with an anonymous function.

Comment: …or just call `ReloadMaxBid` once, so it starts.

Comment: @Zecc yes you can do that, it's just a habit of me using the anonymous function :D @Marcel yes indeed, but maybe he wants to have a initial timeout

Comment: if the return value of data[0].NextReload is -1 as in never do it again, how will setTimeout interpret that? or better yet should i eval the return value and only call setTimeout if iget back a positive int?

Comment: @Azzamattaz You can check for `-1` beforehand and only call `setTimeout` when the value is `>=` 0, if you don't called it it will just stop. I've updated my answer to reflect that.